# Why is allocating an array of Union{T, Missing} an order of magnitude slower than an array of T?

Tags: arrays, performance, julia

Allocating an array of `Union{T, Missing}` is very expensive in Julia. Is there any workaround it?

```
julia> @time Vector{Union{Missing, Int}}(undef, 10^7);
  0.031052 seconds (2 allocations: 85.831 MiB)

julia> @time Vector{Union{Int}}(undef, 10^7);
  0.000027 seconds (3 allocations: 76.294 MiB)
```

Comment: do you have anything specific you are looking for in terms of a more detailed answer?

Comment: I am looking for a workaround, but there was no option in SOF so I just select this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem and as a workaround we used

```
x = Vector{Union{T,Missing}}(undef,1)
resize!(x, newlen)
```

Answer (score 5):

Because if you make a `Union` of `Missing` with a bitstype like `Int` then Julia sets the flag that such a vector initially stores `missing` in each of its entries:

```
julia> Vector{Union{Missing, Int}}(undef, 10^7)
10000000-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 missing
 missing
 ⋮
 missing
 missing
```

If you used non-bitstype then such a flag for each entry does not have to be set as you can see here:

```
julia> Vector{Union{Missing, String}}(undef, 10^7)
10000000-element Vector{Union{Missing, String}}:
 #undef
 #undef
   ⋮
 #undef
 #undef
```

and in consequence the performance is the same:

```
julia> @btime Vector{Union{String}}(undef, 10^7);
  11.672 ms (3 allocations: 76.29 MiB)

julia> @btime Vector{Union{Missing, String}}(undef, 10^7);
  11.480 ms (2 allocations: 76.29 MiB)
```

Comment: I wonder though why the first behaves so much different from `fill(missing, 10^7)`, which is in nanosecond order. Or am I benchmarking wrong?

Comment: `fill(missing, 10^7)` returns a `Vector{Missing}` which is not the same as a `Vector{Union{Missing, Int}}`. The `Vector{Missing}` can be stored more efficiently since it can only hold one value.

Comment: Sure, but I imagined the latter to be essentially just two mallocs plus one memset, and `fill` one malloc plus memset. So where is my mental model off?

Comment: If you have a singleton like `Missing` or `Nothing` and `eltype` is only allowing this type then you do not need to do `fill`. This is exactly how e.g. `Set` is implemented as `Dict` with `Nothing` as values. Check e.g. `Base.summarysize(fill(missing, 10^6))`.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Still, how does _that_ work without filling? Some COW/calloc magic?

Comment: You only need to keep track of the length of the array if it is a `Vector{Missing}` since you know every element will be `Missing`.

Comment: Maybe you could answer that more exhaustively here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70712573/1346276.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that union arrays get zero-initialized. You can see the code that decides this here:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/3f024fd0ab9e68b37d29fee6f2a9ab19819102c5/src/array.c#L191

This ends up as a call to `memset`:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/3f024fd0ab9e68b37d29fee6f2a9ab19819102c5/src/array.c#L144-L145

So as a check, we can compare `zeros` vs allocating the union array:

```
julia> @time Vector{Union{Missing, Int}}(undef, 10^7);
  0.020609 seconds (2 allocations: 85.831 MiB)

julia> @time zeros(Int, 10^7);
  0.018375 seconds (2 allocations: 76.294 MiB)
```

Quite comparable timings.

However, I don't think this performance difference should end up mattering in your application unless you have structured it in a quite strange way. There is very little work you can do with that array until the allocation time becomes insignificant. For example, just setting the values of the uninitialized array makes the timing vs the union array quite similar:

```
julia> function f()
           a = Vector{Int}(undef, 10^7)
           for i in eachindex(a)
               a[i] = 1
           end
           a
       end;

julia> function f_union()
           a = Vector{Union{Missing, Int}}(undef, 10^7)
           for i in eachindex(a)
               a[i] = 1
           end
           a
       end;

julia> @time f();
  0.015566 seconds (2 allocations: 76.294 MiB)

julia> @time f_union();
  0.026414 seconds (2 allocations: 85.831 MiB)
```

Comment: And if we go into details then note that although currently `Vector{Union{Missing, Int}}(undef, 10^7)` fills the array with `missing` this behavior is not guaranteed (it is considered to be an implementation detail) - what is guaranteed is that it will be filled with some value. Use `Vector{Union{Missing, Int}}(missing, 10^7)` to ensure that the vector is filled with `missing`. The same is with unions with `Nothing`.

Comment: But this can become bottleneck. For example, on my system, if I allocate array with 10^9 elements and (for any reason) do it 100 times, 400 seconds is wasted just for allocating something that I need to fill with something else anyway.

Comment: Not really. There isn't any meaningful computation you could do on those 10^11 elements in 400 seconds. Even initializing them to a value would take roughly 400 seconds.