# Where does the magic of singleton arrays come from?

Tags: arrays, julia, runtime

The following difference between `Vector{Missing}` and `Vector{Int}` surprised me (in a positive way):

```
julia> @btime fill(20, 10^7);
  15.980 ms (2 allocations: 76.29 MiB)

julia> @btime fill(missing, 10^7);
  20.603 ns (1 allocation: 80 bytes)

julia> Base.summarysize(fill(20, 10^7))
80000040

julia> Base.summarysize(fill(missing, 10^7))
40

julia> typeof(fill(20, 10^7))
Vector{Int64} (alias for Array{Int64, 1})

julia> typeof(fill(missing, 10^7))
Vector{Missing} (alias for Array{Missing, 1})
```

Given that `fill(missing, n)` does not result in some optimized structure like [`FillArray`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/FillArrays.jl), how is this optimization on singletons implemented?  I guess it falls out in some way automagically from the fact that singletons have zero size, but how?

I tried to read [array.c](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/array.c) and [julia.h](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/julia.h), but can't really follow the details enough.  Maybe the real question is instead *how are singletons handled by the runtime system*...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic answer is that for an `a = Array(T)` Julia always allocates `sizeof(T)*length(a)+40` bytes. Since `sizeof(Missing) == 0`, this means it doesn't allocate any bytes related to the length.

Indexing occurs on [line 569 of `array.c`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/352266160f14d9d0fcfc3552c6f83f86d9bd4944/src/array.c#L569), and the relevant line is

```
jl_value_t *r = undefref_check((jl_datatype_t*)eltype, jl_new_bits(eltype, &((char*)a->data)[i * a->elsize]))
```

When the size of the array is zero, `a->data[i * a->elsize]` refers to the beginning of `a->data`.  The content of this is, however, completely irrelevant: when `eltype` has zero `jl_datatype_size`, `jl_new_bits` [ignores the data pointer](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/63f62943e13d47c917e4136bc13c062a2b09fbe1/src/datatype.c#L808) and instead returns the `instance` field from the `eltype`, which is the singleton object.

Comment: I thought as much, but how does indexing work with this? Is there a magic value at the beginning of the allocated block (after the length zero data part) to tell the call "I'm empty, but look up the singleton here"?

Comment: Ah, this is the special place: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/63f62943e13d47c917e4136bc13c062a2b09fbe1/src/datatype.c#L808. `jl_new_bits` ignores the null pointer `data` and returns the instance stored in the `jl_datatype_t` of the singleton.

Comment: You could probably either add another answer with that info or suggest an edit to Oscar's answer to include that since it's part of what you wanted to know. (Comments on SO are somewhat ephemeral.)